# Gridview why all visible rows are set to dirty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm using the BulkEditGridView control as discussed http://roohit.com/site/showArc.php?shid=bbb62, and it's perfect for my needs.  The problem I'm having is that whenever I save, every visible row (I have paging enabled) gets updated.  Stepping through the code I see that grid.DirtyRows.Count is equal to the number of items per page minus 1 when I click the save button.

I can't find where rows are set as dirty.  Any suggestions where I can look?

My code-behind has only this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.Common;

public partial class MSDS_MSDS_Admin_GridUpdate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gridMSDS.DataKeyNames = new String[] { "id" };
            gridMSDS.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the aspx code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MSDS/MSDS.master" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false" CodeFile="GridUpdate.aspx.cs" Inherits="MSDS_MSDS_Admin_GridUpdate" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="RealWorld.Grids" Namespace="RealWorld.Grids" TagPrefix="cc2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="Server">
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="100%" />
    <cc2:BulkEditGridView ID="gridMSDS" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
        DataSourceID="sqlData" EnableInsert="False" InsertRowCount="1" PageSize="20"
        SaveButtonID="btnSave" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" Visible="false"
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChemicalTitle" HeaderText="ChemicalTitle" SortExpression="ChemicalTitle" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SheetDate" SortExpression="SheetDate">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SheetDate") %>' Width="85px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                        TargetControlID="TextBox1">
                    </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SheetDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Filename" HeaderText="Filename" SortExpression="Filename" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Manufacturer" HeaderText="Manufacturer" SortExpression="Manufacturer" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UsageDept" HeaderText="UsageDept" SortExpression="UsageDept" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Notes") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlStatus" DataTextField="DisplayValue"
                        DataValueField="Value" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NCLWebConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="getOptionList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="msds_Status" Name="ListName" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlStatus" disabled="true"
                        BackColor="White" DataTextField="DisplayValue" DataValueField="Value" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NCLWebConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="getOptionList" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="msds_Status" Name="ListName" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Health" SortExpression="Health">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <center>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Style="text-align: center" Text='<%# Bind("Health") %>'
                            Width="25px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </center>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Health") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fire" SortExpression="Fire">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <center>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Fire") %>' Width="25px"></asp:TextBox></center>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Fire") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reactivity" SortExpression="Reactivity">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <center>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Reactivity") %>' Width="25px"></asp:TextBox></center>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Reactivity") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateUpdated" HeaderText="DateUpdated" SortExpression="DateUpdated"
                ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdatedBy" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="UpdatedBy" SortExpression="UpdatedBy" />
        </Columns>
    </cc2:BulkEditGridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlData" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NCLWebConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [ChemicalTitle], dbo.dateOnly([SheetDate]) As [SheetDate], [Filename], [Manufacturer], [UsageDept], [Notes], isnull([Status], 4) as [Status], [Health], [Fire], [Reactivity], [DateUpdated], [UpdatedBy] FROM [msds_Sheets] ORDER BY [ChemicalTitle]"
        UpdateCommand="msds_UpdateSheet" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ChemicalTitle" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SheetDate" DbType="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Filename" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Manufacturer" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UsageDept" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Health" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Fire" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Reactivity" Type="Int16" />
            <asp:ProfileParameter Name="UpdatedBy" Type="String" PropertyName="Username" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Testing Procedure is as follows:
-Load the page.
-Edit something in the first row.
-Click save button.

Comment: See if this post helps http://onthefencedevelopment.com/?p=68

Comment: I'm having trouble with the Dirty Rows in the gridview, not the entire page being flagged as dirty.

Comment: This sounds like the behavior it should have. What's the problem?

Comment: No definately not.  The dirty rows should only be the ones I've edited.  Shouldn't they?  One of my fields is a UpdatedDateTime field, and I don't want unchanged rows to get a new datestamp.

Comment: The purpose is that its easy to edit any column in any row.  A user could edit all of them, but probably will just edit some of them.

Comment: I cannot duplicate this behavior, even with paging enabled. (i.e. it only updates the rows that I change.)  Can you post your `BulkEditGridView` tag with its attributes, please?  Also, can you post anything relevant to the pager as well?

Comment: @Joel- Please see edit for relavant markup.  I wasn't sure initially what to post.

Comment: Thx, I'll have a look. What version of the .NET framework are you using?  (BTW, I think you need to remove the "-" at the end of `@Joel-`, otherwise SO will attempt to notify `Joel-`, and I won't see it.)

Comment: Something similar happened to me where the dropdownlist was causing the dirty flag. Its pre-bound value was nothing, but the top blank value of the rendered dropdown on post apparently did not equal nothing.  I wound up coding around it by setting the isDirty = false if the required fields were also blank.

Comment: @Joel I didn't know that.  I usually put - to after someone's tag, I'll stop doing that.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: @Eric - I do have a dropdown....  What choice do I have if I need a dropdown there?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? I have created a cut down version of your code with a small test database, and I am still unable to reproduce the undesirable behavior that you are seeing. The `Status` drop down does not cause any problems, even when the underlying data contains null values for the Status field. I still want to do some tests with the CalendarExtendar, and will let you know if that turns up anything.

Comment: Targeted for asp.net 3.5

Comment: I did some additional testing, including the `SheetData` field with `CalendarExtender`. I've tried quite a few things, and your code is working fine for me. A few questions:  (1) What does your `btnSave_Click` do? It isn't needed for save, since the BEGV control does that for you. (2) Do the rows come back as dirty even if you edit nothing? (i.e. just press `Save`), (3) What is your test sequence? (i.e. give me a few details about what you do, paging, etc., before pressing `Save`), (4) Are there any scripts on the page (other than the ones that are added by the `ToolkitScriptManager`)?  Thx

Comment: @Joel -See my latest edit.  I've changed the code listings to include the entire current file, and added some detail about my test procedure.  No special scripts are there.

Comment: I still can't make it break, so we need to figure out what's different about my code/environment and yours. If it were me, I would: (1) create a new dummy master page, and have your page reference that. (2) Comment out the `TemplateField` for `SheetDate` and replace it with a `BoundField`. (You need this because I don't think your `CalendarExtender` will work without your master page, which apparently has the `ToolKitScriptManager`.)

Comment: If changing the master page doesn't help, try temporarily replacing the the `TemplateField` for `Status` with a `BoundField`. I don't think the drop down is an issue, but it would be good to eliminate all doubt.

Comment: If neither of the previous suggestions help, then we need to look at possible differences between your version of BEGV and mine.

Comment: @Joel -You should post these suggestions as an answer.  You've done so much work already, I'd like to have the option of awarding you the bounty.

Comment: Sure, I have been planning to post the results when it is clear that we are getting somewhere. I'll go ahead and do that now. I also have some suggestions for streamlining what you've got.  BTW, part of my motivation in doing the work is that it is a learning exercise for me. I've learned a lot from this.

Comment: If necessary, we can use SO chat to figure this out in real time. I need to step away for a few mins, will be back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have posted looks fine. My test code is almost identical to yours, but I cannot produce the unwanted results you are seeing.

The most significant difference between your code and mine is that I don't have the code for your master page. My master page is the default page created by VS 2008. Other than that, the differences are in the SQL and the underlying database. Specifically,  I am not using any stored procedures, and I have made reasonable assumptions about the data types involved: the `ID` is `int`, `Status` is `smallint`, `SheetDate` is `Date`, `DateUpdated` is `DateTime`, and everything else is `varchar`.

**EDIT:** Your `SheetDate` appears to be just the date portion of an underlying `DateTime` value from the database. The fact that your query transforms the underlying data value for display purposes is not relevant, because the grid view can't tell that it is getting a modified value. **END OF EDIT**

Here are a few suggestions for diagnosing the problem:

- Test without master page, or with a
  very simple dummy master page that is
  guaranteed not to have scripts that
  interact with the `BulkEditGridView`.
  Since the `ToolkitScriptManager` is
  apparently on your master page, you will
  need to either move the script
  manager control to the page itself,
  or else temporarily get rid of the
  `CalendarExtender` element, which
  requires the script manager.
- Temporarily replace the `Status`
  template field with a bound data
  field, to eliminate possibility of
  interaction with the `DropDownList`.
  The drop down list did not cause
  problems in my tests, but there may
  be subtle differences between your
  code and mine.
- If neither of these help, then a possible cause is a problem in your
  version of the `BulkEditGridView`.

**EDIT - Additional suggestions for diagnosis:**

- Based on examination of the source code for `BulkEditGridView`, it appears that the code is properly tracking which rows of the grid are "dirty". Therefore, the most likely cause of a spurious dirty row is that one or more controls in the grid are incorrectly detecting a change to their data content.  You can detect this in the debugger, using the source code for `BulkEditGridView`, rather than the pre-compiled DLL.
- Set a breakpoint at the start of `HandleRowChanged`, the event handler which detects changes in any cell of the grid. By examining the `sender` parameter of that object in the debugger, you can tell which controls in the grid are undergoing value changes.  In particular, you will be able to tell which controls, if any, are incorrectly triggering a value change event.
- Once you determine which control(s) are incorrectly reporting that their value has changed, you can focus on **why** this is happening.

**END OF EDIT**

Some other suggestions to improve the code are as follows. **These will not solve the original problem**, but will make the code cleaner:

- In all of the template fields, remove the `ItemTemplate`s. They can never be used, since the `BulkEditGridView` forces every row to be in the edit state.
- In the code behind, the `BindData()`
  call is not needed, since the source
  data is specified in the declarative
  markup, and therefore the grid view
  control will automatically bind the
  data.

Comment: I can try it without, but I believe I put that databind() in there while trying to make the sorting and paging work.  Also, the Item Templates are probably not needed.  I just let them autogenerate at first, then I changed things.

Comment: @MAW - Databind shouldn't be needed for sorting and paging, since that requires postback, so your Databind code wouldn't execute then anyway. I kind of thought the item templates were autogenerated. It wasn't obvious to me that they weren't needed until I looked at the BEGV source code.

Comment: SheetDate is actually a datetime which I'm using a user defined sql function to truncate into just a date.  I tried replacing the RealWorldGridView dll, no dice.  I also tried adding a scriptmanagerproxy onto the content page, no dice.

Comment: Just tried the BEGV code in a new web form, same behavior.  I'm going to re-download the the BEGV and replace my dll.

Comment: Fresh dll, new web form, and with databind() commented out, same thing.

Comment: @Joel -I think I might just have to do this manually.  Can I make my own dirty rows listing and loop through it myself to save rows?

Comment: I guess you could do that, but I don't think you can improve on what BEGV is doing.  The real issue is what causes the GridView to detect that a row has changed. That's what we need to pinpoint. Do you have the source code?

Comment: I just re-downloaded the dll from http://aspnetrealworldcontr.codeplex.com/releases/view/1674.  Source code is there.

Comment: Have a look at how they track dirty rows. I think you will come up with pretty much the same thing. Set a breakpoint at the beginning of `HandleRowChanged`. That handles changes due a TextBox, CheckBox, or a DropDownList. See AddChangedHandlers for where sets up the event handler.

Comment: I couldn't do it better, agreed.  But why isn't his working!?

Comment: That's what we have to figure out.  Need to isolate what control is causing the problem. Set the breakpoint on the `HandleRowChanged`, see if you can figure out which control is causing spurious dirty.  The handler should fire once for each changed cell (not row) of the GV. So it may fire multiple times for a single row. One thing you could try is to, one at a time, comment out the code that adds the handlers in `AddChangedHandlers`. e.g., comment out adding the handler for drop downs. If the problem goes away, you know that DDL is the culprit.  If DDL is the problem, then we can focus on why

Comment: I think I'm missing something.  When using the dll (the precompiled version of the control) Visual Studio doesn't debug within it.  How can I debug that code?

Comment: You will have to use the source code, not the precompiled dll. There are a couple of ways to do that.

Comment: I created a chat room that we can use, if you want. Using comments is too slow.  Click on chat and search for "Bulk" in the room filter.

Comment: @MAW ignore earlier remark about commenting out stuff in `AddChangedHandlers`. That will work, but you can just look at the `sender` argument when the handler fires to figure out which control is responsible for the event.

Comment: @MAW - Due to work changes, I will not be available until after 5pm CST, going forward. But I am still interested to find out what is causing this, without regard to bounty, I will edit my answer to include the additional diagnosis suggestions made in comments above, and will look for any results/comments after work. Good luck.

Comment: @Joel -Any time you are able to check and respond is fine by me.  Your deserve the bounty, but I will continue troubleshooting and posting the results here.

Comment: The problem is the Textbox Calendar extender.  Its causing all rows to be set as dirty.  Commenting that out makes it work right.  Now I have to find a way to use it without breaking the BEGV, as I'm not going to let my user's type in dates.  That way lies madness.

Comment: I updated the ACT, no change.  I tried to wrap the textbox and calendar extender in an updatepanel, and the save code couldn't see the textbox.

Comment: @MAW - Well, that's progress! But still a mystery because I'm using CalendarExtender, with no problems. To make sure that you are actually using the updated ACT, check the version number of the ACT dll in your web site's bin directory.  The most recent for .net 3.5 is version number `3.5.50401.0`. If the version number is correct, you might try deleting the ASP.NET temporary files in the .NET v2.0  framework, just to make sure you aren't picking up an earlier version of the JIT-compiled code.

Comment: @Joel -Which temporary files are you referring to?

Comment: @MAW - Please ignore remark about deleting temp files. It won't hurt, but it won't help either. The location of these files for .net 3.5 is `%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files` I have had to delete these on several occasions due to problems with web page code and stuff in App_Code. I was thinking that DLLs in the bin directory got copied to the temp folder as well, but they don't. Also, JIT code (i.e. native code from JIT compiler) is not placed in the temp folder. It is cached in memory. Apologies for confusion.

Comment: I am at a loss, since I cannot duplicate this. See if the code works if you just return `sheetDate` in your query, without calling `dbo.dateOnly`. I have tried my code with a full `DateTime` value here, and it works fine. I can't see how truncating the date would make any difference whatsoever, but it is the only significant difference between my code and yours. I'll try to check for a response at lunch time.

Comment: HOLY HELL!  It likes things without dbo.dateOnly()!  WTF!  Ok, so now we found the problem (even if we're not sure why), is there a way I can only show the date part in the textbox?  My user's will be confused with a time there.

Comment: I am so mad about this!  Why is it so hard to find documentation on things?  The answer is to format the datetime into just a date within the bind tag of the textbox like so:  `Text='<%# Bind("Sheetdate", "{0:M/dd/yyyy}") %>'`.  All fixed!  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @MAW - Glad it's fixed. I've used stuff like that where there is insufficient documentation and you are reduced to reinstalling stuff and one-at-time disabling what you **think** is the most likely cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in BulkEditGridView control, but this is what I found at Matt Dotson's [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2005/11/09/real-world-gridview-bulk-editing.aspx)

You may not be able to know that the row has been updated, unless you watch for the change explicitly. First, for each row add a change handler

```
protected override void InitializeRow(GridViewRow row, DataControlField[] fields)
   {
      base.InitializeRow(row, fields);
      foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
      {
         if (cell.Controls.Count > 0)
         {
            AddChangedHandlers(cell.Controls);
         }
      }
   }
```

You can use this snippet

```
private void AddChangedHandlers(ControlCollection controls)
   {
      foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
      {
         if (ctrl is TextBox)
         {
            ((TextBox)ctrl).TextChanged += new EventHandler(this.HandleRowChanged);
         }
         else if (ctrl is CheckBox)
         {
            ((CheckBox)ctrl).CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.HandleRowChanged);
         }
         else if (ctrl is DropDownList)
         {
            ((DropDownList)ctrl).SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.HandleRowChanged);
         }
      }
   }
```

Then you define a dirty row list and add rows that needs to be updated there (in the event handler)

```
   private List<int> dirtyRows = new List<int>();
   void HandleRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
      GridViewRow row = ((Control) sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
      if (null != row && !dirtyRows.Contains(row.RowIndex))
      {
         dirtyRows.Add(row.RowIndex);
      }
   }
```

Finally, to commit changes, iterate through all the dirty rows and save changes

```
   public void Save()
   {
      foreach (int row in dirtyRows)
      {
         this.UpdateRow(row, false);
      }

      dirtyRows.Clear();
   }
```

And here is your ASPX code

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SaveButton" Text="Save Data" />
   <blog:BulkEditGridView runat="server" id="EditableGrid" DataSourceID="AdventureWorks" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LocationID" SaveButtonID="SaveButton" >
      <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="LocationID" HeaderText="LocationID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LocationID" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Availability" HeaderText="Availability" SortExpression="Availability" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="CostRate" HeaderText="CostRate" SortExpression="CostRate" />
      </Columns>
   </blog:BulkEditGridView>
```

Comment: I saw that, but looking at the source code of the control, that's all built into the control.  The give-aways are the use of this., base., and override.  This is part of what's confusing me.

Comment: This seems to be the code of the BulkEditGridView control itself, so theoretically you just need to call just Save method. I can't see in your code that you actually called Save, have you?

Comment: His article says that isn't needed.  He's very proud of providing a good developer experience.  I'll see if it makes any difference.

Comment: No effect with an explicit call to Save();

Comment: @MAW74656 - You are correct. `Save()` is called internally by the control when the `Save` button is clicked. Clicking it again won't do anything, because the save method clears the `dirtyRows` list (see code above in this answer).